# How to show one division on clicking button and hide another division at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a Quiz. For that I have multiple choice questions.
I dont want to show all the questions on the same page at a time. I want that only one question should be displayed at a time and when button is clicked, question in next division should appear and previous question should hide. At last, when user submits the last question, it should take it to the results page that would be basic php. But how to do that show/hide part? 
I am a newbie in these. Please don't take me as a professional.

here's my code.

```
    <html>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option1">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option2">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option3">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option4">
    <button id ="button1">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt1">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt2">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt3">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt4">
    <button id ="button2">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
    <input type="radio" name="que3" value="1">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3"value="2">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3"value="3">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3" value="4">
    <button id ="button3">Next</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to add a class to the `div` elements, but just as working example for your current markup using jQuery, following example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oov7sn2/) for the show/hide part.

Hide all `div` sections with CSS, display the first `div` initially, and when the button is clicked, hide all `div` elements and display the next `div` based on the index of the current `div` in case it's not the last `div` / question.

CSS:

```
div {
  display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("div:eq(0)").show();
  $("button").click(function () {
    var questions = $("div").length;
    var current = $(this).parent("div").index();
    $("div").hide();
    if (current < questions - 1) {
        $("div:eq(" + (current + 1) + ")").show();
    } else {
        alert("no questions left, go to results");
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried to add this as stack snippet but for reasons unknown didn't get it to work, therefore above Fiddle instead.

**Update:** For the additional question in the comment, you can e.g. save the value of each answer as `data` attribute like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("div:eq(0)").show();
  $("button").click(function () {
    var questions = $("div").length;
    var current = $(this).parent("div").index();
    var answer = $(this).parent("div").find("input:checked").val();
    alert(answer);
    $(this).parent("div").data("answer", answer);
    $("div").hide();
    if (current < questions - 1) {
        $("div:eq(" + (current + 1) + ")").show();
    } else {
        var answers = [];
        $("div").each(function(i){
        answers[i] =  $(this).data("answer");
        });
        console.log(answers);
        alert("no questions left, go to results");
    }
  });
});
```

and then loop over all question `div` elements to fetch the values and add them to an array for further processing / checking if each answer is true or not. Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oov7sn2/1/) displaying the array as console log message.

Comment: I implemented your code. It's running perfect but how to fetch values at end.? I mean, once all responses are noted down, then how to fetch values of each response and then check whether the answer is correct or not?

Comment: That is, how to add a form in it and take it to the page "results.php" where all responses would be displayed. In php.. Like here http://jsfiddle.net/dzqj5jcq/

Comment: @AshwiniPurohit Just updated my answer with a suggestion for storing the given answers as `data` attribute value.

Comment: But at last it should show all the values on a different page named "result.php" . How to store and display all the values to a different page . You are using javascript to store values. I need to store in php variables.

Comment: @AshwiniPurohit Please don't get this wrong, but that's more like a different / follow-up question. Your original question was the show / hide part. For the php variables: currently (following the suggested approach) when all questions are answered you would have an array of the answer values in an array. Next step is to check if the answers are true or false. You could use a second array with the values of the correct answers for comparison and then populate the php variables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

hope you may be able to show the first page with a single question. Now use buttons id as the next div id of the question. Let me clear you if a next button with id 2 has been clicked the next div with id 2 will be shown and remaining div & buttons less then 3 or greater then 3  will be hidden. At last you may determine the last page by the id of the  last finish button can be shown.

Comment: Not happening. I want to take a quiz. and then display the result to result.php.

Answer (score 0):

This works ([demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0goapsxn/))
I made a little change to your **html**, look here:

```
<body>
    <div class = "question">
    First Question
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option1">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option2">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option3">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option4">
    <button class = "btn-next" data-question-number = "1">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div class = "question">
    Second Question
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt1">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt2">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt3">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt4">
    <button class = "btn-next" data-question-number = "2">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "question">
    Third Question
    <input type="radio" name="que3" value="1">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3"value="2">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3"value="3">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3" value="4">
    <button  class = "btn-next" data-question-number = "3">Next</button>
    </div>
```

**Css:**

```
.question{
    display:none;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
//show the first question on the page loads
$("button.btn-next").eq(0).parent().fadeIn()

$(".btn-next").on("click", function(){
    var question_number = $(this).data("question-number")
    // question_number = index + 1
    var next_question = $("button.btn-next").eq(question_number).parent()

    if(question_number < $(".question").length){
        var parent_row =$(this).parent()

        parent_row.hide()
        next_question.fadeIn()

    }else{
        //your logic here           
    }
});
```

Comment: It works perfect. But how to fetch all values? I mean, I want to display all the submitted responses on a page "result.php" . How to fetch all the submitted responses on the page result.php ?

Comment: Post your php code and consider accepting the answer if it works for you.

Comment: My result.php code should display all the responses. My aim is to take a quiz and then at last, output their marks. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try. The code is commented wherever possible.

```js
// This is short for $(document).ready(...)
$(function(){
  // Store our questions in a variable
  var $questions = $('.question');
  
  // Show the first question
  $questions.first().show();
  
  // When clicking the <button> in ny of the questions...
  $questions.find('button').on('click',function(){
    // ...store the currently visible question, then...
    var $visibleQuestion = $questions.filter(':visible');
    
    // ...if there's a next question....
    var $nextQuestion = $visibleQuestion.next('.question');
    console.log($nextQuestion);
    if ($nextQuestion.length === 1){
      // ...hide the visible question....
      $visibleQuestion.hide();
      // ..and show the next.
      $nextQuestion.show();
    }
    // If you want, you can check for quiz completition in this else section
    else {
      // Quiz finished
      alert('You finished the quiz!');
    }
  });
  // Optionally, change the text of the last question's button
  $questions.last().find('button').text('Finish Quiz');
});
```

```css
/* Initially hide all questions, we'll show them later with JavaScript */
.question { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The <div> elements now have the class "question" -->
<div id="div1" class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option1">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option2">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option3">
    <input type="radio" name="que1" value="Option4">
    <button id ="button1">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt1">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt2">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt3">
    <input type="radio" name="que2" value="Opt4">
    <button id ="button2">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="que3" value="1">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3"value="2">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3"value="3">
    <input type="radio"  name="que3" value="4">
    <button id ="button3">Next</button>
</div>
```

As for the PHP result processing part, I would suggest that you ask that as a separate question.